# how to set the font for Cpropertysheet?

Tags: mfc

By default CPropertysheet uses System Font which creates problem in non-english language, so would like to set the font explicity which will be compatible with all languages.

Answer (score 0):

CPropertySheet is derived from CWnd, so it has a SetFont member function. Have you tried that?

When using SetFont it is necessary to make the CFont object a member variable so it will live as long as the window.

Comment: Yes....I have tried creating CFont object as member variable for the CPropertySheet then also it is not changing. And I use Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Which text are you trying to change?  The text on the tabs is displayed by a tab control which is an embedded member of CPropertySheet. So the solution may be that you need to call SetFont on the tab control. CPropertySheet::GetTabControl can be used to give you access to the control, as shown in this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dftahdhz.aspx

Comment: Not for specific controls but I want to change the desired font for all the controls in the Cpropertypages and Cpropertysheet. By default, I have hard coded my CPropertypages for some font using resource editor but during runtime it changes to system font irrespective of the font which I set, I think it is because Cpropertysheet by default uses system font and it changes the Cpropertypages too. I want to know how can 
I change the font for CPropertysheet and Cpropertypages during runtime. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these resources:

- [CPropertySheet size increased in Windows 8.1 chinese](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/341f78b9-ab68-4244-93ab-c0aeb3e927b6/cpropertysheet-size-increased-in-windows-81-chinese?forum=vcgeneral)
- [mfc property sheet getting resized on japanese operating system?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dafcc012-7667-4854-87cf-712728ce1ad6/mfc-property-sheet-getting-resized-on-japanese-operating-system?forum=vcgeneral)
- [Changing font of Property Sheet dialog](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?124935-Changing-font-of-Property-Sheet-dialog)

MFC contains bug in `_AfxChangePropPageFont()` and `AfxGetPropSheetFont()` methods. It has been fixed for Japanese but not Chinese.